# What is the dimensionality of a MWC-like random generator?

Tags: random

For the usual, 32-bit, version of the Mersenne Twister algo, the dimensionality is 623.

What is the dimensionality of a MWC random generator?

Comment: Can you link to an unambiguous definition of that kind of 'dimensionality'?

Comment: The maximum size N such that I can use the PNRG to simulate a vector of N (mutually independent) uniform variable.

Comment: According to Wikipedia, a lag-1 MWC is identical to a LCG. In this particular case the dimensionality is 1. If you permit a certain (high) number of hyperplanes, you can choose a modulus/multiplier combination and run the spectral test (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator#Advantages_and_disadvantages) I hypothize that for MWC the dimensionality is at most as high as the lag.